# NA returned while using strptime

Tags: r

I have this data frame which gives me Date and Time columns. I am trying to combine these 2 columns but strptime is returning NA. i want to understand why is it happening?

```
x <- data.frame(date = "1/2/2007", time = "00:00:02")
y <- strptime(paste(x$date,x$time,sep = " "), format = "%b/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `%m` and `%Y` in place of `%b` and `%y` (`%b` - Abbreviated month name in the current locale on this platform. `%y` - Year without century (00–99)).

```
strptime(paste(x$date,x$time,sep = " "), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2007-01-02 00:00:02 IST"
```

For understanding the `format`, it is better to check `?strptime`

---

Or we can use `mdy_hms` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
with(x, mdy_hms(paste(date, time)))
#[1] "2007-01-02 00:00:02 UTC"
```